# PWA - SignInWithPopup doesn't work in my Angular app

Tags: progressive-web-apps, service-worker, google-signin, angular-service-worker

I'm using signinWithPopup for Google login in my Angular app and everything works fine. It looks like this:

```
  doGoogleLogin(){
    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
      let provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
      provider.addScope('profile');
      provider.addScope('email');
      this.afAuth
      .signInWithPopup(provider)
      .then(res => {
        this.router.navigate([{outlets: {modal: null}}], { queryParamsHandling: 'merge', relativeTo: this.activatedRoute.parent}).then(()=>{
        this.notificationService.showSuccess('Logged In', 'You are now logged in.');
      }); // NAVIGATES BACK TO WWW.MYAPP.COM
      }, err => {
        // console.log(err);
      })
    })
  }
```

However, it doesn't work in my PWA version of it that I have installed on Android. Popup with 'Sign in - Google Accounts' opens, I click on my mail address, and it redirects me to `myapp.firebaseapp.com/_auth/handler?state=AMBjfrojirjETC` (the page is hosted on firebase) - however, the page is blank and doesn't get redirected to `www.myapp.com` (in web app everything works fine). When I close it, I'm back in my PWA and the login didn't happen. It's my first PWA and have no idea what goes wrong.

Comment: Any success? Were you able to solve it? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add your domain to the `Authorized domains` list in https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project//authentication/providers